# Obtengo valores nulos al intentar obtener un valor del .env en laravel

Tags: laravel, env

tengo esta key en mi archivo .env

```
GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY=MIAPIKEY
```

he intentado obtenerla de la siguiente manera en mi servicio:

```
$apiKey = env('GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY');
```

al comienzo todo estaba bien hasta que tuve que hacer un `artisan config:cache` y un `optimize` y ahora ya no puedo obtener la key de esa manera, he intentado también con

```
$apiKey = Config::get('app.GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY');
```

pero sigo obteniendo valores nulos

cómo puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Ensaya ejecutar `php artisan config:clear` y `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @Pipe gracias, pero vuelve a suceder lo mismo después, he publicado una respuesta con la solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me faltó añadir el nombre de la Key al archivo config/app.php

```
'GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY' => env('GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY'),
```

luego para llamar a la key, importé config

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
$apiKey = Config::get('app.GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY');
```

y por supuesto, se tiene que añadir también en el archivo .env

```
GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY=CLAVECLAVECLAVE
```

recomiendo hacer esto en lugar del clásico `env('GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY');` ya que tarde o temprano sucederá este problema al hacer `config:cache`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching